# Position an element relative to an ancestor or earlier sibling

Tags: css-float, css-position, css

I had the following code which gave me my desired appearance, but I always felt the document order was incorrect, as the sidebar should come later:

```
<h1>header</h1>
<div style="float:right">variable height sidebar</div>
variable height content
<h2>sub-section</h2>
```

The sidebar, on desktops, may extend into the following section, which is fine. I would rather have that than a big white space (i.e. the h2 does not clear:right).

On mobile platforms however, I wanted to linearise the sidebar, and for it to come after the content. Therefore I had to change the document order, and get it looking as I had it before. Obviously, I could do this:

```
<h1>header</h1>
<div style="overflow:auto">
    <div style="float:left">variable height content</div>
    variable height sidebar
</div>
<h2>sub-section</h2>
```

And leave a big gap below the content, if it is short.
But I was wondering if it was possible to keep the content "unfloated", yet still position the sidebar under the h2 element on desktops.

The earliest browser I care about is IE7. I do not want a JavaScript solution. I have tried negative top margins and I have tried absolute inside relative positioning, with a wrapper element, but neither gave a good solution. To summarise: I want the sidebar to come second in document order; on desktops, I want the h2 to clear the content but not the sidebar, and the sidebar to be in the top-right just under the h1; on mobiles I want the content and sidebar both in flow.

Is this possible?

Comment: js fiddle to show an example? at a glance i'd say putting the sidebar in a `<div>` (or `<aside>` if  HTML5), that way you have more fine-grained control over the presentation - this is a general tip rather than a solution at this point

Answer (score 1):

As I understood the task, you need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/yDx9G/

And if you'll need the sidebar to be at the bottom of everything, and if you're targeting only modern mobile platforms, you can try to change vertical the order of the elements using the `flexbox` or `table` behavior in the media queries.

There are two great articles about this issue on adactio.com:

1. [Article about flexbox](http://adactio.com/journal/4778/)
2. [Article about using `display:table` for changing order of elements](http://adactio.com/journal/4780/)

Comment: The `flexbox` solution will work for mobiles, but means the document order must remain sidebar first for desktops (since IE < 10 doesn't support it). The `display:table-caption` solution, whilst allowing document reordering, is intended for navigation-on-top rather than a sidebar, and using `right`, though deprecated, would still not give the same behaviour as `float:right`. Upvote for the relevant and recent links to one of my favourite CSS blogs :-)

Comment: You don't have to make layout on flexbox/table on both desktop and mobile platforms, just only on the mobile via media query, CSS is flexible enough to have completely different layouts on desktop and mobile platforms.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. I meant that I want to document order to be content-first, therefore the CSS support for displaying the sidebar needs to be on my lowest end desktop browser. I don't have a problem with mobiles, that was just the cause of finally changing the document order. I am now trying sniffing IE7 and below, and serving that the old document order (nav first), and everything else gets content-first, using `display:table` instead of floating. The white space under the sidebar is more acceptable.

Comment: Ah! I hope, I finally understood the task, updated the answer with an example of a layout. If I understood wrong, correct me.

Comment: Yep, you now understand the layout I am trying to achieve. Though the question, remember, was "is it possible to avoid floating the content?" which your jsfiddle code still does. I have modified it a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/3yUq5/2/ to unfloat everything after the sidebar, and we get to approximately where I was at when I came to stack overflow! If the answer is "No", add a new answer, and I'll just accept that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered wrapping the content in containers? For example:

```
<div id="content">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <h2>sub-section</h2>
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
  variable height sidebar
</div>
```

You could then use CSS positioning to place them anywhere you want. A really simple version:

```
#content {
  float: left;
}

#sidebar {
  float: right;
}
```

As seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/euYHq/).